# Python: how check emails with smtplib faster

Tags: python, email, smtp, smtplib

I need to check a lot emails, thousands of emails.
I use `smtplib` to do it and I have some problem.
It's takes too much time (although I use multiprocessing and as usual 32 processes).
And sometimes I have an error to some email (timeout) or another error and I don't take any result for this.
But If I execute it again, I won't get an error, but can get errors for another email.
What I do wrong in my code and how can I improve that to have more accuracy and less errors.

```
def check_email(email, mxRecord):
            time.sleep(2)
            host = socket.gethostname()
            try:
                server = smtplib.SMTP()
                server.set_debuglevel(0)
                addressToVerify = email
                server.connect(mxRecord)
                server.helo(host)
                server.mail('me@domain.com')
                code, message = server.rcpt(str(addressToVerify))
                server.quit()
                if code == 250:
                    res_email = email
                    res = str(num) + ' ' + str(res_email)
                    print res
                    return res
                else:
                    continue
            except:
                continue
```

Answer (score 0):

you just loop throu all mail at the same time use threading...

```
def check_email(email, mxRecord):
        time.sleep(2)
        host = socket.gethostname()
        for line, line 1 in itertools.izip(email, mxRecord)
            try:
                server = smtplib.SMTP()
                server.set_debuglevel(0)
                addressToVerify = email
                server.connect(mxRecord)
                server.helo(host)
                server.mail('me@domain.com')
                code, message = server.rcpt(str(addressToVerify))
                server.quit()
                if code == 250:
                      res_email = email
                      res = str(num) + ' ' + str(res_email)
                      print res
                      return res
                else:
                    continue
                except:
                    continue

m = threading.Thread(name='daemon', target=check_email(email,mxRecord))
m.setDaemon(True)
m.start()
```

sould look like this

Comment: What is  `name='daemon`?

Comment: the deamon from theading do import threading a deamon is started to check every email,mxRecord

Comment: I use `multiprocessing` to parallel. Or it something different?

Comment: plz post whole code snipset, dont see u using     multiprocessing u posted a loop which checks all email, mxRecord at the same time